# How to access and modify custom settings in vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a vscode extension which has some custom settings. I have defined the settings in package.json like so:

```
{
"contributes": {
        "configuration":[
            {
                "title": "Extension",
                "properties": {
                    "Codegenx."A Float": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "default": 1.0,
                        "description": "A sample decimal number"
                      }
                      
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I access these setings in my main extension? And also make sure that I get the updated value if the user changes the settings through the settings.json file or through the VsCode UI?

Comment: you can set up a hook on `Settings changed` in the extension, read the extension  API doc on how to get the `Configuration`

Comment: Could you please provide a link? Thanks,

Comment: how difficult is it to search the API page for `Configuration`

Comment: Sorry, but I could not find anything on the [vscode api  page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api)

Comment: Play with the sample and everything should be clear, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/configuration-sample

Comment: have you looked at the menu on the left, one (1) of the links on that page is the page you should be reading